# Cannot connect with CQL to Cassandra 2.0.10

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3, datastax

In the server config, I've disabled thrift (`start_rpc: false`), because presumably that is now legacy. Server starts up fine:

`INFO 12:23:09,658 Starting listening for CQL clients on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042...
INFO 12:23:09,668 Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it`

If I then try to start CQL, I get this error:

`C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin> .\cqlsh.bat
Connection error: Could not connect to localhost:9160`

Port 9160 is the thrift port. I was under the assumption that CQL was supposed to run on the native format.

If I try to force the port:

`C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin> .\cqlsh.bat localhost 9042`

I get this:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\..\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh", line 2092, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\..\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh", line 2075, in main
    single_statement=options.execute)
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\..\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh", line 490, in __init__
    password=password, cql_version=cqlver, transport=transport)
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\lib\cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip\cql-1.4.1\cql\connection.py", line 143, in connect
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\lib\cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip\cql-1.4.1\cql\connection.py", line 59, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\lib\cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip\cql-1.4.1\cql\thrifteries.py", line 159, in establish_connection
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\lib\cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip\cql-1.4.1\cql\cassandra\Cassandra.py", line 1265, in describe_version
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\lib\cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip\cql-1.4.1\cql\cassandra\Cassandra.py", line 1275, in recv_describe_version
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\lib\thrift-python-internal-only-0.9.1.zip\thrift\protocol\TBinaryProtocol.py", line 126, in readMessageBegin
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\lib\thrift-python-internal-only-0.9.1.zip\thrift\protocol\TBinaryProtocol.py", line 206, in readI32
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\..\lib\thrift-python-internal-only-0.9.1.zip\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 63, in readAll
EOFError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cqlsh for Cassandra 2.0.x uses Thrift to communicate with server.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6307

Comment: I assume that means that even though cqlsh claims to use version 3.1.1, I can't really use CQL3 features then?

Comment: You can. cqlsh uses so called "cql over thrift"

Comment: I'm confused. I've seen elsewhere, and it's the headline of the Jira issue, that CQL3 data is not compatible with thrift.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: Well, new Cassandra release (v2.2): 
`start_native_transport: true` using port 9042. And thrift rpc server is disabled by default (`start_rpc: false`). And I can use CQL 3.3 :D
Also cqlsh is using port 9042 by default to connect to Cassandra.

Meaning, you should switch to Cassandra 2.2 to get the full features out of Cassandra.